# Data structuring - Is there a better alternative to Map<Integer, List<List<Date>>>?

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to organize some data into date ranges. I have a series of identifiers, and each of them has some date ranges for which it is active. Date ranges consist of a beginning and end date, which I will save in a List of two Date elements.
So in the end, I have a `Map<Integer, List<List<Date>>>`, which looks a bit cumbersome. Is there any better way of saving this information?

Comment: As for me, this structure is fine, in style of java.

Comment: It's better to define your custom Type which holds startDate and endDate and use List<YourType> instead of List<List<Date>>. It will look more cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try guava MultiMap

```
ListMultimap<Integer, List<Date>> mm  = LinkedListMultimap.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you could split it into classes:

```
class A {
  Date from;
  Date until;
}

class B {
  List<A> list = ...
}

class C {
  List<B> list = ...
}
```

of course with meaningful names. So you can use `C` in your map.

You are probably going to have methods on each class level anyway, so later on you don't need to worry about the location of these methods - they just fit nicely into this structure, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you not interested in including guava or apache.

```
public class DateRange {

    private final Date start;
    private final Date end;

    public DateRange(Date start, Date end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public boolean contains(Date date) {
        // Use whatever comparison method is best 
        // for your particular date objects here
        return date.compareTo(start) >= 0 && date.compareTo(end) <= 0);
    }


    // Getters, Setters if applicable, etc.
}
```

Now `Map<Integer, List<DateRange>>` Seems very easy to read.  To break it up even more, you can create an Identifier class like [Rene Links's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17318010/1907998%20Rene%20Link%27s%20answer) suggests, and just replace the apache commons Range with a list of your `DateRange`s like so:

```
public class Identifier {

    private final int id;
    private final List<DateRange> ranges;

    public Identifier(in id, List<DateRange> ranges) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ranges = ranges;
    }


    public boolean isActive(Date date) {
         for(DateRange dr : ranges) {
             if(dr.contains(date)) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following, which both looks better (subjective) and is more correct domain-wise:

```
Map<Integer, List<DateRange>>
```

Where `DateRange` could simply be:

```
public class DateRange {
  Date start;
  Date end;
}
```

(Modify qualifiers and add getters/setters/methods as you see fit)

**Bonus tip:** Also, I'd like to point out that for most real-world date tasks, `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` is hard to use and isn't always well-defined. **I suggest you consider using [Joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html).** Which just happens to have an [`Interval`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?org/joda/time/Interval.html) class that should work well for your scenario.